# jQuery in a wordpress template page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am developing a tool for my Wordpress website using jQuery, I am quite new at this but what I'm trying to do is not that hard.

My script is enqueued, i've read that with the NoConflict mode i can't use `$` so I use `jQuery` instead.

```
function Calculator()
    {
        var result = jQuery('result');
        if (jQuery('day').value == "" || jQuery('month').value == "" || jQuery('year').value == "") {

            return;
        }
        result.update('<span class="result">processing</span>');

        jQuery('form').request({
            onComplete: function(transport) {
                result.hide();
                result.update(transport.responseText);
                new Effect.Appear(result, { duration: 0.5 } );          
            }
        });

}
```

My problem is I got error everywhere :
update is not function
request is not function
etc...

There is something i'm obviously doing wrong but can't figure out what...

thanks a lot !

Comment: In which file you enqueued your script?

Comment: i enqued it in my template file (and of course the script is declared in the functions.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors you are seeing ("update is not function request is not function") describe the problem - those really are not jQuery functions.

It looks like you're trying to update an HTML element with ID or class "result".  To do that, [use .html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
var result = jQuery('.result'); // "." to select the element with class result
result.html('something');
```

For .request, it looks like you are trying to do a POST or GET of a form.  If so, [use .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), .post(), or .get().  Note though you'll need to add a few more details, eg:

```
jQuery('form').ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: someurl,
    data: somedata,
    onComplete: ...
});
```

Also, if your Calculator() function can be called while the page is loading, make sure it (or whatever calls it) is wrapped in document.ready:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    ...
});
```

An unrelated issue, to check the value of say a form input with class "day", you need to use:

```
jQuery('.day').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are fetching the value using class then you have to do it like this:

```
jQuery('.result').val()
```

or if using id use it like:

```
jQuery('#result').val()
```

in jquery we use `.val()` function to get value instead of value.

Comment: Thanks i didn't know that, i did these modifications but i still have "result.update is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

Is update, request exists in jquery?

you can use like this rather than writing again and again.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(".result").html("<span>Processing..</span>");
```

Comment: this works, but actually you're right, "request" may  not exist in jquery... How can i replace it ? This code is supposed to get some text created in a php file when the user send a form